# How to add some default event for all form while creating in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have some common `event` or setting for all forms that create automatically  when adding a `Form` to project?

For example I want to have some override event that is common for all of The Project Forms, so I want to write it once  and accept for all forms and speed up developing and decrease mistakes.

**Update:**

in `BaseForm`:

```
public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int _originalExStyle = -1;
    bool _enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering = true;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (_originalExStyle == -1)
                _originalExStyle = base.CreateParams.ExStyle;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            if (_enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering)
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            else
                cp.ExStyle = _originalExStyle;

            return cp;
        }
    }

    public void TurnOnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering(bool command)
    {
        _enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering = command;
    }
    private void BaseForm_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TurnOnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering(true);
    }

    private void BaseForm_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TurnOnOffFormLevelDoubleBuffering(false);
    }
```

in other forms in inherit `BaseForm` like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

the problem is in `form1` the events not fire.

what's wrong or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a new base for `Form` and have all your forms use your custom form class instead :)

Comment: Or you could make a form factory, which calls a specific method, when you create a new form though it. But it is difficult to give you a more specific answer, without some additional details and/or code examples.

Comment: Yes you can set up form first time and then export as template (it wil import by visual studio automatically). Then it will available in template list for use. @Jaxi ask to create a new base. Means if you want to add more winforms in your template they will also follow your settings.

Comment: @Jaxi, i did it before and i create a base form with several override events and inherit it in other forms, but events not fire while form running.

Comment: @Abhiverma, good point, but i will have same codes in every forms, what about that?

Comment: @Noceo, can you give me a sample for `form loading` event?

Comment: Overriding the OnResizeBegin() method is normally the correct way to do this, call base.OnResizeBegin().  But there is an easy explanation for "it does not work", the CreateParams property only gets used when the native window is created.  Happens very early, before the Load event fires.  Certainly not when the user resizes the window so changing the bool has no effect at all.  Technically you could call base.RecreateHandle() but it is a very nasty flash, the exact opposite of what you tried to accomplish.  You'll have to throw this away.

Comment: @Hans Passant,you mean that i should write `CreateParams` property separately for each Form, is it true? if yes, how to achieve that?

Comment: No, that is not what I meant.  Set a breakpoint on the CreateParams property getter and you'll see what I was talking about.  Note how it is never called when you are busy resizing the window.

Comment: @HansPassant, i did it in normal form and override `CreateParams` property and setting the value of `_enableFormLevelDoubleBuffering ` in `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` event worked fine, why it dosen't work when i inherit it?